# In javascript, what does the line var meta = MetaCoin.deployed(); mean and what does it return?

Tags: truffle, javascript

I am following the official Truffle docs to create a Dapp and am reviewing the code. I am repeatedly seeing the line

```
var meta = MetaCoin.deployed();
```

What is the deployed function? What does it return?

Comment: Why don't you do a `console.log(meta);` and see for yourself?

Comment: I did that and I understand now. Thank you for helping me understand vs. just learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Truffle example test](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/testing) has:

> // Get a reference to the deployed MetaCoin contract, as a JS object.
>
> var meta = MetaCoin.deployed();

`deployed` is only in Truffle and it's a helper/shortcut so that you don't need to deal directly with the ABI and the address that your contract was deployed to.  It's like these steps [in web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract):

```
var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(<abiArray>);
var contractInstance = MyContract.at(<address>);
```

Truffle has config files so it knows what the ABI and address of the contract is.